# JSONP request using jquery $.getJSON not working on well formed JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I'm not sure is it possible now from the url I am trying. Please see this url: http://www.heiaheia.com/voimakaksikko/stats.json

It always serves the same padding function "voimakaksikkoStats". It is well formed JSON, but I have not been able to load it from remote server. Does it need some work from the server side or can it be loaded with javascript? I think the problems gotta to have something to with that callback function...

JQuery is not requirement, but it would be nice.

This (callback=voimakaksikkoStats) returns nothing (firebug -> net -> response), and alert doesn't fire:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.heiaheia.com/voimakaksikko/stats.json?callback=voimakaksikkoStats", function(data){
    alert(data);
})
```

but this (callback=?):

```
 $.getJSON("http://www.heiaheia.com/voimakaksikko/stats.json?callback=?", function(data){
    alert(data);
})
```

returns:

```
voimakaksikkoStats({"Top5Sports":[],"Top5Tests":{"8":"No-exercise ennuste","1":"Painoindeksi","2":"Vy\u00f6t\u00e4r\u00f6n ymp\u00e4rys","10":"Cooperin testi","4":"Etunojapunnerrus"},"Top5CitiesByTests":[],"Top5CitiesByExercises":[],"ExercisesLogged":0,"Top5CitiesByUsers":[""],"TestsTaken":22,"RegisteredUsers":1});
```

But I cannot access it... In both examples the alert never fires. Can someone help?

Comment: I am trying to get this from remote server using JSONP. Server always return voimakaksikkoStats - and not dynamically given callback-function. Is this causing problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function voimakaksikkoStats(obj) {
    alert(obj.TestsTaken);
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.heiaheia.com/voimakaksikko/stats.json"></script>
```

I never got it working with jQuery, but the simple code above solved my problems. I found help from Yahoo: http://developer.yahoo.com/common/json.html

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function voimakaksikkoStats(stats) {
  var ul = new Element('ul');
  ul.insert(new Element('li').update('Registered users: '+ stats['RegisteredUsers']));
  ul.insert(new Element('li').update('Tests taken: '+ stats['TestsTaken']));
  ul.insert(new Element('li').update('Top5 sports: '+ stats['Top5Sports'].join(', ')));
  $(document.body).insert({'bottom': ul});
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http:/www.heiaheia.com/voimakaksikko/stats.json"></script>
```

This example uses Prototype.js to create list with some data from given stats, and then puts this list at the bottom of document body.

Comment: Yeah, I got it right just before this - but this would have surely helped me too!

Answer (score 0):

is the script trying to fetch json from http://www.heiaheia.com also on http://www.heiaheia.com ?

if not this is the cause, it's currently not authorized to make request (using javascript) to another server than the one serving the script

Comment: Yes, remote server and we are trying to use JSONP for this.

Answer (score 0):

To get your test function to work, try changing to `callback=?`

Comment: Ah, I have mistake on my question. The JSON response is when I am using callback=?. If I have callback=voimakaksikkoStats then the response is empty.

Answer (score 0):

If the your request goes to anonther domain try using **jsonP** method. Search for jsonP docs

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP

Comment: Yes, this is what we are trying to do. Though the heiaheia erver always return voimakaksikkoStats - and not dynamically given callback-function. Is this causing problems?